# C# UWP File output for encryption and decryption code seems to stop working for files over 128 MB

Tags: c#, encryption, uwp

Wrote some C# UWP code to encrypt files using the new encryption engine, and recently added code to make it be able to handle more bulky files by splitting the files up into parts and encrypting each part seperately since the libraries encrypt and decrypt functions won't take gigantic buffers. Now, it seems to be in some cases either outputting nothing to the file or giving a "system.exception" error in the Visual Studio debugger, which as you can imagine, isn't very helpful. Here's the code for this part of the program:

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task encryptFile(StorageFile file, string key)
        {
            Loading.IsActive = true;
            string HashAlgorithmName = HashAlgorithmNames.Md5;
            HashAlgorithmProvider HashProvider = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmName);
            CryptographicHash HashObject = HashProvider.CreateHash();
            Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer keyAsBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(key, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf16BE);
            HashObject.Append(keyAsBuffer);
            Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer hashedKeyAsBuffer = HashObject.GetValueAndReset();
            string hashedKey = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(hashedKeyAsBuffer);
            key = hashedKey;
            string algorithmName = SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7;
            SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider encryptionProvider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(algorithmName);
            Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key));
            CryptographicKey fullKey = encryptionProvider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyBuffer);
            Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
            byte[] fileBytes = ReadToEnd(fileStream);
            Stream writeFileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
            IEnumerable<byte[]> splitFileBytes = ArraySplit(fileBytes, 100000000);
            writeFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            foreach (byte[] fileBytesFor in splitFileBytes)
            {
                Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer fileBuffer = fileBytesFor.AsBuffer();
                Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer encryptedFileBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(fullKey, fileBuffer, null);
                Stream encryptedFileStream = encryptedFileBuffer.AsStream();
                byte[] encryptedFileBytes = ReadToEnd(encryptedFileStream);
                await writeFileStream.WriteAsync(encryptedFileBytes, 0, encryptedFileBytes.Length);
                writeFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            }
            fileStream.Dispose();
            writeFileStream.Dispose();
            Loading.IsActive = false;
        }

        private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task decryptFile(StorageFile file, string key)
        {
            string HashAlgorithmName = HashAlgorithmNames.Md5;
            HashAlgorithmProvider HashProvider = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmName);
            CryptographicHash HashObject = HashProvider.CreateHash();
            Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer keyAsBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(key, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf16BE);
            HashObject.Append(keyAsBuffer);
            Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer hashedKeyAsBuffer = HashObject.GetValueAndReset();
            string hashedKey = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(hashedKeyAsBuffer);
            key = hashedKey;
            string algorithmName = SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7;
            SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider encryptionProvider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(algorithmName);
            Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key));
            CryptographicKey fullKey = encryptionProvider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyBuffer);
            Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
            byte[] fileBytes = ReadToEnd(fileStream);
            Stream writeFileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
            Loading.IsActive = true;
            writeFileStream.SetLength(0);
            IEnumerable<byte[]> splitFileBytes = ArraySplit(fileBytes, 100000000);
            writeFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            foreach (byte[] fileBytesFor in splitFileBytes)
            {
                Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer fileBuffer = fileBytesFor.AsBuffer();
                Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer decryptedFileBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(fullKey, fileBuffer, null);
                Stream decryptedFileStream = decryptedFileBuffer.AsStream();
                byte[] decryptedFileBytes = ReadToEnd(decryptedFileStream);
                await writeFileStream.WriteAsync(decryptedFileBytes, 0, decryptedFileBytes.Length);
                writeFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            }
            fileStream.Dispose();
            writeFileStream.Dispose();
            Loading.IsActive = false;
        }

        public static byte[] StreamToByteArray(Stream inputStream)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[375000000000000000];
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int count;
                while ((count = inputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    memoryStream.Write(bytes, 0, count);
                }
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static byte[] ReadToEnd(System.IO.Stream stream)
        {
            long originalPosition = 0;

            if (stream.CanSeek)
            {
                originalPosition = stream.Position;
                stream.Position = 0;
            }

            try
            {
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];

                int totalBytesRead = 0;
                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(readBuffer, totalBytesRead, readBuffer.Length - totalBytesRead)) > 0)
                {
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

                    if (totalBytesRead == readBuffer.Length)
                    {
                        int nextByte = stream.ReadByte();
                        if (nextByte != -1)
                        {
                            byte[] temp = new byte[readBuffer.Length * 2];
                            Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, temp, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                            Buffer.SetByte(temp, totalBytesRead, (byte)nextByte);
                            readBuffer = temp;
                            totalBytesRead++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                byte[] buffer = readBuffer;
                if (readBuffer.Length != totalBytesRead)
                {
                    buffer = new byte[totalBytesRead];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, totalBytesRead);
                }
                return buffer;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream.CanSeek)
                {
                    stream.Position = originalPosition;
                }
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<byte[]> ArraySplit(byte[] bArray, int intBufforLengt)
        {
            int bArrayLenght = bArray.Length;
            byte[] bReturn = null;

            int i = 0;
            for (; bArrayLenght > (i + 1) * intBufforLengt; i++)
            {
                bReturn = new byte[intBufforLengt];
                Array.Copy(bArray, i * intBufforLengt, bReturn, 0, intBufforLengt);
                yield return bReturn;
            }

            int intBufforLeft = bArrayLenght - i * intBufforLengt;
            if (intBufforLeft > 0)
            {
                bReturn = new byte[intBufforLeft];
                Array.Copy(bArray, i * intBufforLengt, bReturn, 0, intBufforLeft);
                yield return bReturn;
            }
        }
```

Comment: A couple of things. 1. Do not use ECB mode in new work and update legacy work ASAP, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret.
 2. The padding should only be used for the last part, all others should be a multiple of the block size (16-bytes for AES) with no padding.

Comment: Your byte array is much too big.